# Log a query that returns no results in Lightswitch HTML

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-lightswitch

What i would like to do is, when a user does a search and the query doesn't return a result. I want to be able to log the string that was searched in another table.

What I'm trying to do seems like it should be straight forward... My first approach was to get the count of a PreprocessQuery.

Example of what i tried:

```
    int count = 0;
    partial void QueryName_PreprocessQuery(string ParamName, ref IQueryable<TableName> query)
        {
            if (ParamName != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(a => a.PropertyName.Contains(ParamName));
                count = query.Count();
            }
        }
```

When i place a breakpoint and step through this method. `count` is always 0 and `query` is always empty. The odd thing is, this query still brings back the correct results. I've tried various different approaches and even started a new Lightswitch project with a single screen and a single query. Same results.

Another example of what i have tried:

```
partial void QueryName_PreprocessQuery(string ParamName, ref IQueryable<TableName> query)
            {
                if (ParamName != null)
                {
                    count = query.Count(a => a.Serial_No.Contains(SerialNumber));                    
                }
            }
```

This method doesn't actually do anything except validate that `query` is empty and `count` is 0. And again... the correct results still show up on my screen.

So this leads me to believe that maybe i shouldn't be trying to get the count in the `_PreProcessQuery` Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're right.  Try changing from QueryName_PreprocessQuery to QueryName_Executed instead.

`QueryName_PreprocessQuery` occurs when the query is being formed and prior to execution.

`QueryName_Executed` is called just after the query is executed and thus should give you the information you're trying to obtain.

You could try something like this:

```
partial void QueryName_Executed(QueryExecutedDescriptor queryDescriptor)
    {
        int resultCount = queryDescriptor.Results.Count();
    }
```

Comment: Those methods have different signatures. Changing the name won't work. Do you know of a way i can get the count in the _Executed method? That would solve my problem. I've tried previously to use the queryDescriptor.Results property but i can't find much  documentation on how to use it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that.  I'll update my answer with something else you can try.

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution. I'll update my post when I get in to work tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah ok.  I found some examples where they called Results.Count() instead of just .Count

Comment: Your latest edit was the the same route i ended up taking. However, i casted queryDescriptor.Results to IEnumerable<IEntityObject> but that's not needed just to get the count. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Not because you solved my problem but for others who may come across the same problem as I. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!